# CSS Is it possible to align a submit button with input fields?

Tags: html, css, scss-lint

Currently I get :

[image: form 1]

I am trying to align the button with the input fields to get displayed like that

( *Note: I can add a margin-left: 40px  to the button csss description, but I am not sure it's the best option* ) :

[image: form target]

with the following template and scss

**LoginPage.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="login-page">
    <h1 class="title">Login to existing account</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="login()" class="form form--login grid">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="login__email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="login__email" class="input--block" v-model="email" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="login__password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="login__password" class="input--block" v-model="password" />
      </div><!-- /.row -->
      <div class="row">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </div><!-- /.row -->
    </form>
  </div><!-- /.login-page -->
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .login-page {
    form {
      .row {
        padding-top: 5px;
        label {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 140px;
          text-align: right;
        }
        input {
          display: inline-block;
          text-align: left;
        }
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Try using the `table` tag with inputs in the second column.

Comment: you can do the same as the other by adding a `label` but empty

Comment: @Temani , thanks , I tried to add an empty label... doesn't work...

Comment: @Temani , sorry for my previous comment . .. it WORKS fiFINE as you swrotene , tested in jsFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/  but in my template I guess the button  css is modified by the global css ... I need to chekc it and update my scoped scss

Comment: you may also change `button` with `input submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to give `margin` in the submit button. You can give a `label` for submit button.

Check this:

```
  <div class="login-page">
    <h1 class="title">Login to existing account</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="login()" class="form form--login grid">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="login__email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="login__email" class="input--block" v-model="email" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="login__password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="login__password" class="input--block" v-model="password" />
      </div><!-- /.row -->
      <div class="row">
        <label></label>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </div><!-- /.row -->
    </form>
  </div><!-- /.login-page --></code>
```

I only added there one new line:  `<label></label>` in the row of submit button . That's why it can take a width like another fields.

Comment: yes , it works as I commented previoulsy ... I tested it in a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ . ... I need to check my globals button css...

Comment: Great! @erwin .